# Extending Exception : remove message "Uncaught exception XXXX with message"

Tags: php, class, exception, extend

When i extend an Exception class:

```
CustomException extends Exception(){}

throw new CustomException("Houston we have a problem",1);
```

In error:

```
SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
Uncaught exception 'CustomException' with message 'Houston we have a problem' in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 5
CustomException: Houston we have a problem in C:\wamp\www\index on line 5
```

I want only the CustomException message:

```
CustomException: Houston we have a problem in C:\wamp\www\index on line 5
```

Is this possible? Is it an xdebug problem?
Thanks.

Comment: You forgot to present your [testcase](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an xdebug option. In your php.ini you have `xdebug.scream=1` To disable it set it to `xdebug.scream=0`

Scream overrides the `@` "shut up" operator so you will have to turn it off to stop this from happening. Don't forget to restart your server for the changes to take effect.

Comment: i turned off scream, and all xdebug component, it removes SCREAM, but still report double error : Uncaught exception 'CustomException' with message 'Houston we have a problem' in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 5
CustomException: Houston we have a problem in C:\wamp\www\index on line 5

Comment: Then you need to turn off error reporting. In php.ini set `display_errors = off`  For a runtime solution you can set `error_reporting(0);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to catch the exception with a [`try-catch`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) block. Otherwise it will report the exception being uncaught.

For example:

```
try {
  methodThatCanThrowAnException(); // used since I don't know the method you are trying to call
}
catch (CustomException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Um maybe the OP doesn't want to catch it. They want PHP to output the message about the uncaught exception in a sane way, without SCREAMing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit They're asking about the message being uncaught therefore I provided a solution to catch it. How is that not answering the question? If they want to do something else then I can provide another answer.

Comment: So he can catch it without any output. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: The question does not ask for a way to catch exceptions. It asks for a way to stop the output from uncaught exceptions being a SCREAM. Stuart has answered correctly, so there is no need for you and I to continue.

Comment: Yes, im not asking about catch exceptions, its about remove a duplicate report in custom exceptions